# react native app - google api key restrictions

Tags: android, ios, react-native, google-api, restriction

I am trying to restrict our google api keys for the iOS bundle identifier and android package + sha-1.

So far I am always getting:

```
LOG  This IP, site or mobile application is not authorised to use this API key. 
Request received from IP address XX.XXX.XXX.XX, with empty referer.
```

I checked several times - bundle IDs and package names are right, also sha-1 seems right.
Trying without restrictions works of course.

Is there maybe a header that I need to set or something I where I need to let the api know which bundle or package I am actually sending from?